# If something is always false, will it be compiled?

Tags: java

I often use a boolean value to control the output for debugging:

```
void fooBar() {

  boolean debug = false;

  if (debug) System.out.println("will this be in the compile if debug is false?");

  // code for the method

}
```

I was wondering, if this boolean is declared inside the method as false. Then will it be compiled or not? (since it's redundant).

In case my explaining is not clear, will it be compiled as above or like this:

```
void fooBar() {

  // code for the method

}
```

Comment: It will be compiled. So hard to check?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out?

Comment: I wonder if the OP asks what happens in the compiled byte-code?

Comment: If you declare `debug` to be `static final` my understanding is that the code will be compiled out.  This is to permit "conditional compilation".  (Though note that the "omitted" code must still be syntactically correct.)

Comment: (The supposed "dupe" does not provide an adequate answer.)

Comment: @HotLicks "to compile out" is apt to cause confusion. I guess you mean "not compiled".

Comment: @laune - "Compile out" is a common phrase in computing.

Comment: @HotLicks Starting with D.Gries' book on compilers I have read a lot of English literature on compilers, and I've never read that one before.

Comment: do you refer to the compilation from Java to byte-code or the JIT compilation if the method gets hot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the control variable is `static final` --

```
public class CondComp {
    static final boolean debug = false;
    public void doIt() {
        if (debug) System.out.println("Here we are");
    }
}

Compiled from "CondComp.java"
public class CondComp {
  static final boolean debug;

  public CondComp();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
()V
       4: return

  public void doIt();
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

As can be seen, nothing is generated for the `println`.

And here is the same with `debug` set to `true`, for disbelievers:

```
Compiled from "CondComp.java"
public class CondComp {
  static final boolean debug;

  public CondComp();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
()V
       4: return

  public void doIt();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/
io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String Here we are
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.printl
n:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

My understanding is that this holds true even if the `static final` variable is in a different class, but I've never tried it.

This feature is documented in the JLS section on ["unreachable statements"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21), near the bottom of that section, and in the section on ["binary compatibility for final fields and constants"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9).

Comment: `+1` Or in the case of the OP's code, just `final`, as it's a local variable.

Comment: Thanks! Good you added the static final to give a good answer instead of a direct answer to the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will be compiled and bytecode for it will be emitted to the class file (at least by Oracle's compiler). This is trivial to check:

```
javac YourClass.java
javap -p -c YourClass
```

...and look at the result.

If you run it with Oracle's HotSpot, and if it's a hotspot in the code, I wouldn't be surprised if it got JIT'd out.

**However**, as HotLicks [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840454/if-something-is-always-false-will-it-be-compiled/27840535#comment44084883_27840454), adding `final` to it:

```
void fooBar() {

  final boolean debug = false;
//^^^^^

  if (debug) System.out.println("will this be in the compile if debug is false?");

  // code for the method

}
```

...allows the compiler to **not** emit bytecode for it. The code must still compile.